# Margin top not working in mozila

Tags: css

Can you please help me out that how to set margin top in Mozilla browser. With reflecting in internet explorer and chrome. As my following code working fine in chrome and internet explorer. As I searched on internet but still this line is not working. i.e:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {{margin-top: 11px; }}
```

Here is the full code:

```
    #hm-search26 {
        background: url(<xsl:value-of select="$clientImages"/>img/se-search-bg.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
        height: 52px;
        width: 300px;
        z-index: 100;
        float: right;
        position: relative;
        margin: 11px 12px 0 0;
        top : -68px;
        @-moz-document url-prefix() {{margin-top: 11px; }}
        }
```

Comment: First, try to remove two lines: top : -68px; @-moz-document url-prefix() {{margin-top: 11px; }} and see how it works.  It would also help if you include the HTML portion which causes the problem, like in here: http://jsfiddle.net/o15fy6mm/ Best regards,

Comment: still not working sir

Comment: Add the HTML in the jsfiddle. It's hard to debug your app while essential part is missing. Also, it should be: margin: 11px 12px 0px 0px; And, please, be more specific on what exactly is not working. Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `Top:-68px;` Because you applied `position` so it will take this `Top` attribute and than check if your `margin` attribute works or not. I checked in `firefox` and `margin` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this refined CSS snippet and associated test HTML:

CSS:

```
#hm-search26 {
    background: url(<xsl:value-of select="$clientImages"/>img/se-search-bg.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height: 52px;
    width: 300px;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    margin: 11px 12px 0px 0px;
```

}

HTML:

```
<div id="hm-search26">
    <p>Text 1</p>
    <p>Text 2</p>
    <p>Text 3</p>
</div>
```

and you can see how it works in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o15fy6mm/1/

Hope this will help. Best regards,